# Avoid created_at and updated_at being auto generated by sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

How do I define a model for which created_at and updated_at are provided rather than generated?

I'm importing data from somewhere that already has data for `created_at` and `updated_at` fields that I would like to preserve rather than generating whenever the object is created/updated by sequelize (our secondary store).

I've tried every likely permutation of model definition and options to get this to work and still sequelize overwrites my fields with it's own timestamps: `{silent: true}`, etc...

To be clear, the input data has createdAt and updatedAt and I'd like to use sequelize's bulkCreate(), etc such that input values provided are used and stored on the model as created_at and updated_at rather than generated by sequelize.

This is my current model definition:

```
const Lead = sequelize.define('lead', {
  objectId: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'objectId',
    primaryKey: true,
    allowNull: false
  },
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'first_name'
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'last_name'
  },
  phoneNumber: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    field: 'phone_number'
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'created_at',
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    field: 'updated_at'
  }
}, {
  freezeTableName: true, // Model tableName will be the same as the model name
  timeStamps: false,
  underscored: true
});
```

Comment: original code was:
timeStamps: false,

@tyler-brock you shouldn't have edited that. It gets confusing.

Comment: Agreed, I've changed it back, thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The option is

```
timestamps: false,
```

Where `timestamps` is written **fully lowercase**

**Update:**

From looking at the code of the `bulkCreate()` function, [it looks that it always updates the timestamps](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/f7fa33ce0522efcbd6a730ca54565aa321ef8770/lib/model.js#L2205), so, without a patch this is not possible right now

Comment: Ok thank you, i tried that as well though and it still didn't work, i'll change my model definition in the question to reflect that. All of the imported rows still have the same exact createdAt and updatedAt (time of insert), instead of using the provided createdAt and updatedAt.

Comment: looks like i will have to submit a patch, ok then, do you know if the maintainer is pretty active?

Comment: the last commit is from a day ago, so they look pretty active.